# TestNG: how to starte @Test in a certain sequence

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I'm a newbie in TestNG and I face a problem.
    Based on my current code (see below) I have this result:

1. Browser starts (OK)
2. `runTest2()` starts (PROBLEM)
3. `runTest1()` starts (PROBLEM)
4. `tearDown()` starts (OK)

**Goal**: I want this execute in this order (sequence)

1. Browser starts (OK)
2. `runTest1()` starts
3. `runTest2()` starts
4. `tearDown()` starts (OK)

**Question**: How can I achieve this?

```
    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
       //startBrowser
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest1() {
      System.out.printline("runTest1() is started...");
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest2() {
      System.out.printline("runTest2() is started...");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public tearDown() {
        //quit browser
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dependsOnMethods](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations).

```
@BeforeMethod
public void init() {
   //startBrowser
}

@Test
public void runTest1() {
  System.out.printline("runTest1() is started...");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "runTest1" }, alwaysRun=true)
public void runTest2() {
  System.out.printline("runTest2() is started...");
}

@AfterMethod
public tearDown() {
    //quit browser
}
```

The `alwaysRun=true` makes this a soft dependency which means `runTest2` will be executed even if `runTest1` fails.
If you want a hard dependency, leave out the `alwaysRun=true`.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you need to open/close browser for each test method? If not, then you use `BeforeTest` and `AfterTest` instead of `BeforeMethod` and `AfterMethod`.
- Use `priority` parameter for the `Test` annotation to set the order in which these have to be executed.

  ```
  @BeforeTest
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("starts Browser");
  }

  @Test(priority = 1)
  public void runTest1() {
    System.out.println("runTest1() is started...");
  }

  @Test(priority = 2)
  public void runTest2() {
    System.out.println("runTest2() is started...");
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void tearDown() {
      System.out.println("quits Browser");
  }
  ```

I get below output.

```
 starts Browser
 runTest1() is started...
 runTest2() is started...
 quits Browser
```

Comment: Personally I find `dependsOnMethods` much easier to read than `priority`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @David & @Vinoth,

thank you for your quick answer.
Both solutions works fine for me, but in this case I prefer the solution of @Vinoth, because I don't need to start/close the browser between runTest1 and runTest2. :-)

Thank you so much to both of you again. ;-)))

Cheers
Loren

Comment: you need to accept the answer by clicking on the 'tick' whichever solution really helped you.